# Excel Mid Function - Delimiter included in result

Tags: excel, formula

I have a text column with 4 comma delimited "fields" that I am trying to separate into columns. The first 2 and the last work fine. However my third column is returning the , delimiter with the text (at the end)

The text in the concatenated field is in the form:

```
XXX@XX.com,XXX@XX.com,XXX@XX.com,XXX@XX.com
```

and it is the 3rd item I am having problems with. It is returning:

```
 XXX@XX.com
```

Instead of returning

```
XXX@XX.com
```

My statement is:

```
=IFERROR(MID(C42,SEARCH(",",C42,SEARCH(",",C42,1)+1)+1,SEARCH(",",C42,SEARCH(",",C42,SEARCH(",",C42,1)+1)+1)-SEARCH(",",C42,SEARCH(",",C42,1)+1)),0)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use Text to columns on the data tab to split on the `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across.

[image]